# Any straightforward way to capture and initialize multiple return values from function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, stdtuple

In my project there are few functions that return multiple values with the help of tuple and they are used numerously. So I just want to know is there any way in c++ with which I can capture and initialize individual values that are returned by that function call. Below example will explain this question better

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <tuple>
    std::tuple<std::string,int,int> getStringWithSizeAndCapacity()
    {
         std::string ret = "Hello World !";
         return make_tuple(ret,ret.size(),ret.capacity());
    }
    int main()
    {
      //First We have to declare variable
      std::string s;
      int sz,cpcty;
      //Then we have to use tie to intialize them with return of function call
      tie(s,sz,cpcty) = getStringWithSizeAndCapacity();
      std::cout<<s<<" "<<sz<<" "<<cpcty<<std::endl;
      //Is there a way in which I can directly get these variables filled from function call
      //I don't want to take result in std::tuple because get<0>,get<1> etc. decreases readibility
      //Also if I take return value in tuple and then store that in individual variables then I am wasting
      //tuple as it will not be used in code
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Looks to be as direct as it gets.

Comment: wrong thing is my variables are uninitialized

Comment: I usually just define structure for this `struct result { std::string s; int sz,cpcty; }` and use it with `auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in which I can directly get these variables filled from function call I don't want to take result in std::tuple because get<0>,get<1> etc. decreases readibility
>
> Also if I take return value in tuple and then store that in individual variables then I am wasting tuple as it will not be used in code

I understand that the use of `std::get<>()` decreases readability, but you can try to improve it with some comments

```
// get the size of the returned string (position 1)
auto sz = std::get<1>(getStringWithSizeAndCapacity());
```

Anyway, it seems to me that the right way to improve readability is the use of `std::tie()`, and isn't clear to me what's wrong with it for you, or (starting from C++17) also structured binding declarations

```
auto [ s, sz, cpcty ] = getStringWithSizeAndCapacity();
```

If you want avoid to name unused variables (say you are not interested in capacity, by example) you can use `std::ignore`

```
std::string s;
int sz;

std::tie(s,sz,std::ignore) = getStringWithSizeAndCapacity();
```

Unfortunately `std::ignore` can't be used (as far I know) with new C++17 structured binding (maybe something similar from C++20?).